# Adding my local network (where server is) to OpenVPN without using OpenVPN clients on it

Tags: openvpn

I installed OpenVPN on a Funtoo system sucessfully: it works! I use default ips so my server is `10.8.0.1` and the clients conneted to it have IPs auto-asigned.

The problem is that I need to access to some computer on the network and looking on the OpenVPN config file I see that I can push my network:

```
# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
```

The problem is that this is a local ADSL, where the network is the default `192.168.1.X` and I can't change that (I can't access to the router, it's blocked by the ISP).

My question is, I can push a local IP to a OpenVPN ip? Because, if I push `192.168.1.X` to a client that has the same routing at home can conflicts with his network, no?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, I can push a local IP to a OpenVPN ip? Because, if I
>   push 192.168.1.X to a client that has the same routing at home can
>   conflicts with his network, no?

Exactly. It will be conflict between server subnet and client subnet. The solution is use different subnet for the client.

> The problem is that this is a local ADSL, where the network is the
>   default 192.168.1.X and I **can** change that (I can't access to the
>   router, it's blocked by the ISP).

What? The ISP shouldn't block your router. If you have ISP account (I assuming PPPoE username & password), you can reset your modem and re-configure.

Comment: thank you! Sorry it was a **I can't**. We use FTTH here in Spain with Telefonica and they gave you this and a wifi router. To configure a router port I've to access to a Internet website (yes, the provider one, movistar.es/...) and login with my telephone number. Then, in Internet, I can add/remove ports but the router in LAN is totally blocked. I can push 192.168.1.X but seen as 192.168.10.X to the openvpn client?